# How to add apache-tomcat-7.0.53 or apache-tomcat-8.0.5 server runtime environment in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I am using eclipse Kepler 4.3.2, when creating a web fragment project, I want to add server runtime environment,but found only support Apache-tomcat v3.2 to v7.0, I only have apache-tomcat-7.0.53 or apache-tomcat-8.0.5 in my local PC.When clicking 'Downloading additional server adapters',no new version of tomcat listed. Please see below screenshot.
[image]

Please help,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create server,In server view you can able to see the Tomcat server
select the Tomcat server either press f3 or right click and open select **open option**
once you did a panel is opened there you find **"open launch configuration "** click on that.
another panel is opened there you go for **arguments** tab and set your runttime vale under VM arguments with **-DvariableName=value**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, didn't found 'open launch configuration', when launch my tomcat server,got error:The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder lib/jasper-el.jar. And I found I can't add my web fragment project to that server.

Comment: Step 1:Choose Window menu, then Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment.
Step 2:Add the tomcat server.
Step 3: once it did,:Choose Window menu then show view->other>
now type server and select it
now you find server Tab ,now follow my ans above

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat 7.0.53 falls into the `v7.0` category.

1. Select Apache Tomcat v7.0 from the list, making sure `Create a new local server` is checked, and hit `Next`
2. Fill in the location on your local machine for Tomcat 7.0.53 and hit `Finish`

Comment: In my eclipse,only support apache-tomcat-7.0.47

Comment: @Tom I'm using Eclipse 4.3.2 and have added various Tomcat versions, up to 7.0.54.  Regardless, it seems like Abhishek's answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat 8.0 support will be included in Luna. Tomcat 8.0 wasn't final before Kepler shipped--even now it's still in Beta. You can try a Luna build at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php .